# Remote Validation of Uniqueness in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP MVC and SQL Server, I am trying to test the existence of a client before creating him via the uniqueness of his Email's value.

Following a lot of tutorials and solutions, I didn't success to resolve this problem. This is what I've tried :

**ClientController :**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Client cmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ClientManagement cdb = new ClientManagement();
                if (cdb.AddClient(cmodel))
                {

                    ViewBag.Message = "Client Details Added Successfully";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

 public JsonResult IsClientExist(string Email)
    {

        List<Client> cm = new List<Client>();

        return Json(!cm.Any(x => x.Email == Email), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Class ClientManagement :**

```
 public bool AddClient(Client cmodel)
    {
        connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddNewClients", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", cmodel.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", cmodel.Password);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i >= 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

**Model Client :**

```
 public class Client
{

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Remote("IsClientExist", "Client", ErrorMessage = "Email is already exists in Database.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**View Create :**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So what is happening now ?

Comment: @Shyju The validation didn't work, I can create two users (clients) with the same Email

Comment: The naming of your `IsClientExist` is causing an issue with me. If the client exists, it will return false because of the exclamation mark in front of the `Any()` statement. You are also seeing if an empty list has anything in it, that will always be false, so that method will always return true.

Comment: Why dont you check to see if the  users exists and they dont add... if they do update...

Comment: First of all, you are checking against an empty list  in the `IsClientExist` method

Comment: @DavidWatts I understand, so the problem is that the list I call is empty ?

Comment: Not only that. You are negating your result. So if a client does exist in that list, your `IsClientExist` method would return false. So it seems to me like you need to load your data into that list, and also delete the exclamation mark before your `Any()` statement

Comment: @Shyju David think it too, I have to create so a new viewModel or ?

Comment: Just query the database or cache to get the current list of emails and check against that.

Comment: @DavidWatts ok so as I said, should I create a viewModel ?

Comment: @Shyju ok thx I will try and let you know

Comment: A view model has nothing to do with it. You need to load your existing clients from your DB to check against and see if they already exist. You also need to make your `IsClientExist` method return true when the client exists rather than when it doesn't

Comment: @DavidWatts thx for the explication, I have removed the negation and trying now to create a list and fill it with values of Email from DB, is that correct?

Comment: Are you using entity framework code first ? Do you have a `DataSet<Client>` property in your db context ?

Comment: @Shyju No I am not using EF at all, I am using stored procedures

Comment: Just query the existing data and check against that.

Comment: @Shyju You mean like that using (SqlCommand kmd = new SqlCommand("select Email from Client"))
i have problems with filling the list

Comment: @Exact Yes. Take a look at the answer i posted below.

Comment: @Exact precisely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is checking againist an empty list of `Client`. You should be checking against existing data.

You can write a method to check that

```
private bool DoesEmailExist(string email)
{
    var conStr = @"putYourConnectionStringHere";
    var q = "select TOP 1 Email from Client WHERE Email=@email";

    using (var c =new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
       using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c))
       {
            c.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return r.HasRows;
       }
    }
}
```

Now you call this method in your other method. **Your `IsClientExist` should return `false` when the email exist in the system and should return `true` when it does not exist in the database**. So basically you need to negate the result coming back from the `DoesEmailExist` method

```
public JsonResult IsClientExist(string Email)
{
    var r = DoesEmailExist(Email);
    return Json(!r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Keep in mind that this does only Client side validation. **Never trust data coming from client.Always validate on server side**. You should add database level constraints to prevent duplicate emails getting saved in the table as @David Browne mentioned in his answer

Comment: many thanks @Shyju, it is works, only a little mistake.
For the future readers : we have to use Email and not Name the sql command because we are testing on Email :  var q = "select TOP 1 Email from Client where Email=@Email";

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a unique constraint or unique index on Email in the database.

Even when you check for existence before the insert, concurrent requests could lead to duplicates.  So have the database enforce uniqueness and handle the error it returns when you try to insert a duplicate.